# chat.PostMessage with channel name instead of channel id

Tags: slack, slack-api

Can channel name be used in chat.PostMessage instead of channel Id ? Currently in test setup message is being set even if channel name is passed. Is the feature of sending message to a channel with channel name deprecated ? Or is it still allowed ?

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed possible, but discouraged, to use a channel name with `chat.postMessage`. The caution to use is that channel names can change while channel IDs are (usually) forever. You also can't use channel names in most other API method arguments looking for a channel ID. `chat.postMessage` is unique this way and just extra helpful in detecting your intent.